# Eclipse ADT won't run/install android application

Tags: java, android, eclipse, adt

I am new to android application development. I have the eclipse ADT, JDK 7 and an android device (Nexus 5). I made a test app and would like to try it out on my Nexus. However, when I click the green "run" button, nothing happens. My device is connected via USB and also show when i do `adb devices` and also in the DDMS so my drivers are installed correctly. I can also see the logcat for everything happening on my phone in realtime through the eclipse ADT. 
 When I click run, nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

The default Eclipse "Run" behavior is to launch an AVD.  Go to your "Run Configurations" and set it up to prompt you on run rather than assume it should launch an AVD.